# Chrome dialog box jumps from left corner to center when opened

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dialog

When I open a file dialogue box, it opens in the bottom left corner of the screen. Then after a second it closes and reopens in the centre of the screen.

here is a Screen record: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVa4w_ST9qQ

The problem only occurs in Chrome. I tried to reinstall Chrome, it doesn't help.

Version 119.0.6045.159 (Official Build) (arm64)
MasOS Monterey 12.1

Comment: Chrome is trying to be helpful. I don't know of a way to stop it.